# Flutter FlexibleSpacebar not stretching on Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar

I copied the sample code in the Flutter page on using [FlexibleSpaceBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html) class to check it out on iOS and Android. It is working as expected in iOS but not stretching in Android. Is there a compatibility issue on the the version of Android it would work or are there additional steps needed to do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by default Android use `ClampingScrollPhysics` whereas iOS uses `BouncingScrollPhysics`.

You can force it to behave equally on both by setting the `physics` property to `BouncingScrollPhysics` of your `CustomScrollView` or other Sliver view that you're using with it.

add  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics() in NestedScrollView